# swift 4.0: Overriding 'prepare' must be as available as declaration it overrides

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, xcode9, arkit

I was trying to integrate Apple's ARKit example app into my app. As ARKit is only an additional feature, so I need to support lower versions of iOS. I added @available(iOS 11.0, *) tag to all the ARKit example app classes...It almost works except this 1 error: "Overriding 'prepare' must be as available as declaration it overrides". Any idea how can I resolve this issue ?

[Xcode error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zfuTL.png)

Answer (score 6):

Move :

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
     //...
}
```

to the `ViewController` file directly.

It is independent of the `UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate` protocol.

Comment: That0s the right answer. Thanks mate, you've saved my day :D

Answer (score 4):

What worked for me was adding the @available attribute above the method like so:

```
    @available(iOS 11.3, *)
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
         //...
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You're overriding a method called `prepare`, but you're setting it to be less available than it is in the superclass you're inheriting from. If it's `public` in the superclass, it needs to be `public` or `open` when you override it. Likewise, if it's available on iOS versions lower than iOS 11, your overridden implementation must be available on those same iOS versions. Make sure that you've marked your overridden method with the proper access keywords, and that it's still `@available` on all the iOS versions as the superclass you're inheriting from

Comment: But the super class is UIViewController, I cannot make change to Apple's UIKit

Comment: And why override viewDidLoad() etc. works, only this method doesn't work

Comment: This isn't a problem with UIKit. Is `SegueIdentifier` or `VirtualObjectSelectionViewController` marked as being `@available(iOS 11, *)`? If so, try wrapping your use of those in an `if #available` block

Answer (score 0):

In my case, my sub class had "@available(iOS 6.0, *)", but my super did not.  I deleted it from my sub and it worked.  Also could have added to my super, but I am not supporting anything that old so I just deleted.